# Access an object from another class in private method

Tags: java, class, oop, object, private-methods

How do I access an object from another class in private method in Java ?

Simple example to call private method from another class.

***File: A.java***

```
public class A {  
  private void message(){System.out.println("hello java"); }  
}
```

***File: MethodCall.java***

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;  
public class MethodCall{  
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{  

    Class c = Class.forName("A");  
    Object o= c.newInstance();  
    Method m =c.getDeclaredMethod("message", null);  
    m.setAccessible(true);  
    m.invoke(o, null);  
}  
}
```

Comment: Actually here is no major issues in the code you've showed. Why you're considering it as not working?

Comment: This is not a question. The solution for the question is given as example

Comment: You can do this using "reflect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **private** is used only in declared classes and it can not be called from other classes. If you want to use it, you should use it after modifying to **protected** or **public**.

Comment: Sure you can, with the magic of [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev Could the use of the Reflection API in the above code be a common solution to the problem of not using private? It 's a temporary solution.

Comment: what does it mean "temporary solution"? For sure author should double check why it's required to call private methods, but technically it is completely possible, so your statement is incorrect.

Comment: @MinKyuJeong You can do this using "reflect".

Answer (score 0):

Normally Private methods can access only from within the same class. Can’t access the private methods from the  outside class. However, there is a way to access the private methods from outside class.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class PriavteMethodAccessTest{  

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{  

    A test = new A();
    Class<?> clazz = test.getClass();
    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("message");
    method.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println(method.invoke(test));
}  
}
```